# Huggingface mirror in case Huggingface is in Maintenance

Tags: huggingface

Is there a mirror of Huggingface to download models while it is in maintenance, or download all the models while it is not maintenance is the only way?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can download models via modelscope, the website is https://modelscope.cn/models

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).